# SQL query to update every alternate column

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database there are tens of thousands of rows. There are two columns, receipt and coupon. Each 'receipt' value spans 6 rows with the same receipt value, and a different 'coupon' value.

**Ex Database-**

```
receipt    coupon
500        1-mon
500        2-mon
500        3-mon
500        4-mon
500        5-mon 
500        6-mon

501        1-mon
501        2-mon
501        3-mon
501        4-mon
501        5-mon
501        6-mon

502        1-mon
502        2-mon
502        3-mon
502        4-mon
502        5-mon
502        6-mon
```

I'm trying to make an update query which updates the coupon column of each the first instance of the receipt id, then all second instances of distinct receipt like wise, etc

I've tried the following query but this not updating rows properly...

```
update scheme_master set coupon = '3-month' where id % 6 = 1;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: mysql xampp apache server

Comment: what is `id` ? Is that the left number of data of coupon field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` syntax suggests SQL Server, so I think you want something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select sm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by receipt order by id) as seqnum
      from scheme_master sm
     )
update toupdate
    set coupon = cast(seqnum as varchar(255)) + '-month';
```

However, in your example query, you are using "3" and "1", which I don't understand:

```
update scheme_master set coupon = '3-month' where id % 6 = 1;
-----------------------------------^ ----------------------^
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can do:

```
update scheme_master
    set coupon = concat((@rn := if(@r = receipt, @rn := @rn + 1,
                                   if(@r := receipt, 1, 1)
                                  )
                         ), '-month')
    order by receipt, id;
```

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'toupdate as ( select sm.*, row_number() over (partition by ' at line 1

Comment: i need suggestion from you...how to load more than 50000rows in listobx/select box bcoz this takes more loading time on web page..my query like ....select name from master

Comment: If you have another question, you should ask it as a question, with appropriate tags, code samples, and other information.